# Why doesn't this simple django IF statement work?

Tags: python, django

If I output the following in the template:

```
{{ latest_session.chat_room.is_open }}
```

It outputs

```
True
```

But when I do this check:

```
{% if latest_session.chat_room.is_open == 'True' %}
   Online
{% else %}
   Offline
{% endif %}
```

It outputs:

```
Offline
```

Shouldn't it output Online?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`is_open` is probably a `BooleanField`, so its python value is a boolean, not a string. Use `{% if latest_session.chat_room.is_open %}` to check for it.

Comment: yeah you are right, that solves it. Weird though that the auto generated docs didn't mention it was boolean but did so for other fields.

Comment: but be careful that you know it is a boolean and not a text field, if it is a text field with "false" then {% if latest_session.chat_room.is_open %} evaluates to true

Answer (score 3):

`True` is a boolean value, not a string. Use `{% if latest_session.chat_room.is_open %}` instead.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Django Book](http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/chapter04/),

> The {% if %} tag evaluates a variable, and if that variable is “True”
>   (i.e., it exists, is not empty, and is not a false Boolean value), the
>   system will display everything between {% if %} and {% endif %}.

Therefore, you can't do comparisons inside {% if %} tags.  Since `is_open` probably returns a boolean, though, use the following instead.

```
{% if latest_session.chat_room.is_open %}
```

Comment: Not true as of Django 1.2: [basic comparison operators were added](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#operator)